# Why is my Node.js service stopping unexpectedly under GraalVM?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graalvm

I have a fairly simple Node.js service that basically just fields a few HTTP requests. This runs fine via the GraalVM `node` command. However, when I use `node --jvm --polyglot service.js` My Node service dies shortly after starting. Nothing else in the code has changed.

What is interesting is that the following code seems to kill my Node.js service

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb")
console.log("got MongoClient")
```

And when I run Graal Node without `--jvm --polyglot` everything works fine.

If I comment out the Mongo stuff, running with `--jvm --polyglot`, everything works fine.

**What could possibly be going on where trying to run the MongoDB Node.js driver under GraalVM could be causing problems?**

It may not be that it dies, but after starting my HTTP service

```
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running... test at http://${hostname}:${port}/ping`))
```

it no longer accepts HTTP requests. ???

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to raise an issue on GraalVM's repos, probably on the Graal.js one: https://github.com/oracle/graaljs. It could be a bug.

You can also debug the process and maybe that will reveal additional details of what's happening: https://www.graalvm.org/tools/chrome-debugger/

Comment: @EricKolotyluk please try GraalVM 21.2